# Reverse geocoding Nominatim results?

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I need to obtain street intersections from reverse geocoded lat/long, where there is no house number information.

I have a tile server and Nominatim running in Ubuntu 12.04 virtualbox.

I followed intructions to install Nominatim v2 at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation

Is there a way to modify anything to make this work?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Have you succeeded in installing Nominatim? Is it working, or not working, and if not, what error are you seeing?

Comment: @tmcw thanks. The installation was correct. I'm able to use Nominatim. What I need to know if there's a way to get the result of the reverse geocoding adding house number or road intersections.

Comment: @tmcw or may be you can guide me through the process of customising my installation ti make this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to now Nominatim has no support for finding street intersections. However, the developers will welcome your help implementing it.

Perhaps there are other solutions for you, as explained [here](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/29496/how-should-i-search-for-an-intersection):

- If you know the two streets for which you want to find the intersection, then you can retrieve them via two geocoding-queries and compare their nodes for equality (a road intersection in OSM is defined by a node being part of two or more ways).
- If you just know the rough location, then you can grab all surrounding roads (e.g. using the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)) and again start comparing each road with each other one for equal nodes.

Comment: Now I'm dealing with some errors in the output for example in Buenos Aires, Argentina. I can't get ANY street/house number in the results.

Comment: Can you put this in a new question, including the query you are trying?