# Overpass api intersection

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim

I have  a lat-lon point, translated to a street name via nominatim, and I want to find the intersecting streets to retrieve the user something like this:

123rd St, between 456th Bv and 789th Rd

I need to know how to query that.

This is, because in my country (Argentina) OSM doesn't have street numbers when reverse geocoding with nominatim.

Comment: In how far is this question related to Overpass API? What have you tried so far?

Comment: According to this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/102924/32746

Comment: And I don't understand how to query overpass. If you know another way, please, enlight me. It's been a while since I needed to finish this project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could try to use Overpass API with the `around` keyword querying for all highways around your location.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? Thanks